# IIS 7 authorization rules not synced with web.config

Tags: iis-7, web-config, authorization

Is there something wrong with my IIS setup?  I have a 64-bit IIS 7.0 installation.  My site has a web.config, with authorization rules specified.

In IIS Manager, when I open the authorization rules, I had expected the rules from the web.config to be displayed and be editable, with any changes I make synced back to the web.config.  This does not seem to be the case.

From what I can tell, the site obeys whatever rules are put into the authorization settings in IIS, but completely ignores any rules that are put into the web.config.

Is this correct? How is this supposed to work? Is there some way to force a sync?

Comment: Can you post the relevant sections of the web.config?

Comment: Never mind.  Something has caused a flush and the rules are now appearing at the bottom of the web.config, though in a separate system.webserver node.  My original rules were in system.web, which are ingored.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer! It may help the next person if they run into a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that IIS puts the rules into the system.webserver section of the web.config.